# What's the best way to create landing pages in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, landing-pages

I was wondering if the best way to create landing pages and templates for these in Magento is to create cms pages? Write static blocks and then create a new cms page all the time or is there another good way to do this? Is a category page better?

Comment: have you seen this http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/attribute-splash-pro/

Comment: Yeah there are many extensions but I don't wanna use too many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now using category pages and there I add static blocks or whatever I need.
It is a pretty standard process and gives me lots of freedom to create and design the pages the way I want. Using XML Layout updates I can hide/show blocks and every single piece of the website.

I create landing pages for each specific topic or marketing channel, e.g. for PPC I have landing pages, email campaigns, specific products etc.
So I have a "main category" with a speaking name so that this is represented in the URL. For example "promotions" is the main category for email campaigns.

I try to explain it now step by step from the beginning to make it clear.

1. Create Root Category and subcategory (in my example my Cyber Monday page) for the landing page
   [image: Categories for landing page]

---

2. I remove pager and sorter for my products on the landing page so I edit it in the description of the category. There you can also add your normal html content without any blocks to your page already. You can also edit the CSS already from there.

[image: Image 2]

---

3. Use static blocks if you have specific content (this allows all HTML etc.)
   In the Custom Design, I can remove and add these static blocks then for my needs. I have different blocks for different landing pages. So you could create specific ones for all channels and then add these to your needs here to the page as per seen below. Also because I remove the pager I change the initial number of products and so on.
   [image: Block update]

---

4. Just as per usual add the products to the category for your landing page, or just show static blocks depending on your needs

Answer (score 2):

I do static blocks in CMS pages or just straight CMS pages. I don't know if it is the "best way" but it is an easy workflow when creating many landing pages for marketing purposes.

Comment: Ok yeah I thought writing straight CMS pages and templates for these would be the easiest and also effective option

Answer (score 1):

You can create categories with static blocks with or without products or cms pages but both as subdirectories. We use subdomains, high ranking, but you can't do that with standard Magento. If you don't need the site header/footer you can have a subdomain WP or Joomla landing page install, but prefer the landing page sits within the core site, better customer interaction.