# How to create categories wise landing page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, landing-pages

i want to create category wise landing page in magento. i tried to create same with static block but nothing changing in my page. i already followed this url http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-how-to-add-a-category-landing-page/.

let's assume that i have categories like below

- Mens

  - Clothes
  - Aviator

when i click on **Mens** i want to open landing page for this category. so how can i do this.

Comment: Is this question for magento 1.9.x  or you are asking for magento 2.x ?

Comment: You might want to look at this 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54463/whats-the-best-way-to-create-landing-pages-in-magento

Comment: this question for magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/category. This will be the template file for our landing page.
i hope this will work for you

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_categories->count() ?>

<div class="subcategory-grid">
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>

<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()));
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>
<div class="category-container<?php if($i % 3 == 0){ echo ' first'; }     if($i >= 3){ echo ' additional-rows'; }?>">
    <?php $_img = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl() ?>
    <?php if($_img): ?>
        <div class="category-img">
            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($_category);?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $_img?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="category-name<?php if (strlen($_category->getName()) > 32) echo ' small-category-name' ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to call this file from static block.this is what i done i created one static block and puted this code {{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/category/category_listing.phtml"}}. and in manage categories i set display mode static block only and select this static block. but it nothing rendering it displaying blank.

Comment: try this  {{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.categories" template="catalog/navigation/category_listing.phtml"}} then Go to the menu Catalog/Manage Categories,Select the categorie that you want, and in the tab“DISPLAY SETTINGS we set the following information:DISPLAY MODE: STATIC BLOCK CMS Block: Category Listing (the block that you create before) Is Anchor: NO

Comment: thanks Swati for replay, i changed according to your new answer but still it is not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code** will give you all categories & on click them you will goto their landing page.

```
     <?php $_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories() ?>
     <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: but it displaying nothing it give just blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin panel, Catalog, Manage Categories and select your category.

Then on the tab Display Settings, chose your preferred display setting.

Chosing static block allowes you to add a block with your desired content (landing page).

You can also just add a description in General Information