# What is Category Landing Page in MAGENTO ? Explain about it

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to create a category landing page in magento but i have no idea about what is about this page. Please explain about this .

Answer (score 0):

This is just about Category page

Once you create category in backend and access that category url in frontend , thats all that is category landing page......

In Backend , go to Catalog > Manage Categories > Create new category

below links will help you to create category  :

https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-catalog/creating-new-category/

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-create.html

https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-manage-magento-categories-and-products/

below is the category **clothes** you created in backend. once you visit the url : **sitename.com/clothes** , than it will display **Category landing page**

[image]

Comment: Thanks !
Please tell about how to create custom category landing page in magento

Comment: @AnilThakur are you looking for [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147456/custom-top-level-category-landing-page-in-magento) or [link2](https://www.demacmedia.com/mini-tutorial-how-to-add-a-category-landing-page/) , [link3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112458/how-to-create-categories-wise-landing-page-in-magento) , [link4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54463/whats-the-best-way-to-create-landing-pages-in-magento) ?

Comment: I am looking for link 2 but all these are related let me understand to all links you provided

Comment: @AnilThakur please post new question for that.....